# Laravel 5 required_if validation always fails

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

Suppose I have a dropdown list `district_code_c`, one of its option is `other`, so when user select `other`, then system shows an input named as `district_other_c` and user type something, i have a validation rule like this:

```
$present_fields_rules['district_other_c'] = 'required_if:district_code_c,other';
$validator = Validator::make(
  [
     'district_code_c' => $request->get('district_code_c'),
  ],
  [
     'district_code_c' => 'required',
     'district_other_c' => $present_fields_rules['district_other_c']
  ]
);
```

It is working well when i select `other` from dropdown, and noting typed on input, then system shows `*The Current address other city/district field is required when Current address city/district is other.*`
But i type something, then validation fails again.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the rendered dropdown list is a label of the `<option>` which is not necessarily the same as the value that will be submitted.

Comment: option is like: `<option value="other">other</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Just get the your input value before applying validation rules:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
 [
   'district_code_c' => $request->get('district_code_c'),
   'district_other_c' => $request->get('district_other_c'),
 ],
 [
   'district_code_c' => 'required',
   'district_other_c' => $present_fields_rules['district_other_c']
 ]
);
```